# Force closing app when setting the textview to the imported font

Tags: java, android

i have an app with swipe menu and have set a font Roboto font for that in Mainactivity also created a folder in assets and pasted the fonts.
But when i run the app it force closes.
Please help me.

**Mainactivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, Projects.class);
             startActivity(intent);

        break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Aboutus();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Services();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new News_events();
            break;
        case 5:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Gallery.class);
             startActivity(intent2);

        case 6:
            fragment = new Contactus();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

**Logcat**

```
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.paarva.CrescentBuilders/info.paarva.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at info.paarva.slidingmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-04 07:23:40.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3654):     ... 11 more
12-04 07:23:42.341: I/Process(3654): Sending signal. PID: 3654 SIG: 9
```

**Activitymain.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**drawer_list_item.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_home"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**NavDrawerListAdapter**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: In your code,where the line 54,`tv.setTypeface(tf);` is the line 54

Comment: yes,
tv.setTypeface(tf);

Comment: if you remove the typeface means it will not show any error.

Comment: show your activity_main xml

Comment: Then check which one is null tv, or tf, I guess tf is null.

Comment: I have added,please have a look.

Comment: where is textview? of id `title`

Comment: it is in my drawer_list_item.xml.

Comment: that is why u are getting null, inflate drawer_list_item layout in side main ativity

Comment: @Ashfaq where is `title` text view in `XML`

Comment: @–  W-I-Z-A-R-D: can u tell me detailed how to do so,Im new in android thats why.

Comment: @  Yugesh: i will add drawer_list_item.xml code here,please have a look.

Comment: @Ashfaq i have edited my answer check it

Comment: @Ashfaq customized array adapter to load data in list view.Post your customized array adapter class code.

Comment: @Yogesh : i have added my NavDrawerListAdapter.Please see if it is the code u were asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set typeface for text view in `getView`, remove the textview from main activity.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    txtTitle.setTypeface(tf);

    imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
    txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

    // displaying count
    // check whether it set visible or not
    if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
        txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
    }else{
        // hide the counter view
        txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro, This is working properly.you are really great.

Comment: @Ashfaq okay.Accept the answer.It will help to someone to see your question.easy to find which answer is correct.

Comment: @Ashfaq have tick mark in left side of my answer.just click that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Remove `fonts` Try like this

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Inflater layout try like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this); 
View theInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "Roboto-Regular.ttf");
 TextView tv = (TextView) theInflatedView .findViewById(R.id.title);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: did you added `Roboto-Regular.ttf` in assests folder

Comment: just put `Roboto-Regular.ttf` file inside assets folder no need of fonts folder

Comment: i said just put `Roboto-Regular.ttf` file inside `assets` folder no need of `fonts` folder

Comment: @ W-I-Z-A-R-D: force close issue is over but font is normal.

Comment: try with different `.ttf` file because `Roboto-Regular.ttf` is bit similar

Comment: @  W-I-Z-A-R-D: i tried with Roboto bold and other fonts but its not working.

Comment: Thanks alot   W-I-Z-A-R-D, Aman Arora BB for your time.I got the result.Again thanks to all.